# Duplicate duplicate badge question question

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, badges, badge-request

I just came across this old, highly upvoted question on meta: [Give an incentive for finding duplicate questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37466).

In the interest of bumping that thread - almost 5 years to the day later - what do people today think about the giving badges for closing question as duplicates? Seemed like from that old thread, most people were for it, for reasons that are clearly still applicable today.

Andy E's suggestion for badges can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/65894)

Comment: This gets a little harder to justify when dupehammer wielders can close as duplicate by themselves.

Comment: Doesn't that privilege exist because you want them to?

Comment: Of course, but it also makes the badge less valuable/easier for whatever thats worth.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: Well, that's simple to resolve: Using nordic devices of devastation does not count for it, at all.

Comment: @Deduplicator Unquestionably a solution. Of course, then we aren't eligible for it in our gold-badge tags :( (given that we got there, we probably don't need the encouragement anyways though)

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Give an incentive for finding duplicate questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37466).  Can I get a badge for closing this?

Comment: few minutes ago.. i found a possible duplicate (I had already answered) after searching for 10 minutes, wish I would have received a reward

Comment: Also see [Shog's answer here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251913/1708801)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour "Solution: divorce duplicate-marking from closing, provide rewards for solving someone's problem by pointing to an existing question." <-- agree :)

Comment: I think @Barry deserves a duplicate duplicate badge question question badge.

Answer (score -16):

Finding duplicate is a good thing as it link similar questions together which provide the user with even more answers and you want people to do it. So giving badge for it, or even reputation, might be a good idea.

On the other hand, the fact that you can no longer answer a duplicate question is an horrible "feature". You have many duplicate questions that are not exactly the same and you can no longer answer them. Or often, the duplicate question is easier to understand and to answer which creates better answers than the original question. But all that is lost because you can no longer add answers to the duplicate question.

Marking questions as duplicate is a great feature but ONLY IF you could still continue to answer them...

**Update**

A [quote](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) from Jeff Atwood

> What we want is on the order of 4 or 5 similar-but-not-quite-the-same
> duplicates to cover all possible search terms and common permutations
> of the question. It is also OK for these duplicates to have their own
> answers so people who find them don’t have to click yet again to get
> to a good answer.

Comment: Which in turn would give you N questions (N > 1) all of which you have to browse, searching for a set of answers that suits your particular case. Which is not very different from searching through search engines. If you have a better or more general answer for a duplicate question you can still post it under the linked duplicate. Or ask in comments to improve the highest voted answers. Or improve them yourself if they're community wiki.

Comment: @BartoszKP And having N questions is a good thing. I can't count how many thing I couldn't find the original questions from google without the duplicate ones that used totally different wording. You want to have duplicate questions because it makes the site better.

Comment: That's a good point, but still doesn't justify having answers under each of them.

Comment: @BartoszKP A lot of the time, the duplicate is not exactly like the previous one which create different answers and even better answers. The answer you would post for duplicate might not fit for the original one. Often it's the little details in the question that make all the difference

Comment: If the little details in the question make a difference then it's not a duplicate. If they don't make a difference, then the new answer will fit the linked duplicate.

Comment: @BartoszKP And that is exactly the problem I'm denouncing here. If two questions are 95% similar they deserve to be linked together because it adds value. But because they are not exactly the same, the answers to the other question might not be a complete answer for the one that asked the question.

Comment: Duplicate is about answers, not questions, even if it applies to questions.  If another question has answers that answer this question's problem completely, then this question is a duplicate of the other question.  If the other question's answers don't answer this question completely, then the duplication should be removed.  You can link via a comment, or a citation in the question or answer, if you want a link.

Comment: @Yakk This sounds wrong. 2+2 and 2*2 are two different questions that happen to have the same answer and are most certainly not duplicates.

Comment: @jahu 2+2 and 2*2 **are not questions** (unclear what you are asking).  When asking how to add 2+2 or multiply 2*2, you have an implicit generalization (how to add in general, or how to multiply in general).  If you really want "what is the answer to 2+2" and someone else asks "what is the answer to 2*2", the same answer applies to both.  The point of duplicates is to link questions about problems to good answers to the problem.  If someone asks "how do I foo my bar" and someone else asks "how do I baz my nod", and it turns out the way to do it is exactly the same, duplicate away!

Comment: @Yakk Link doesn't provide the same value as duplicate, Often you will see link that direct the user to question that will complement his question (because it's the next step in the procedure) or answer a little details that is only vaguely related to the question but might help some people. On the other hand, duplicate indicate that the 2 questions are very similar and hence it might have a good answer to what you are searching.

Comment: @Gudradain No, having duplicate questions with duplicate answers is terrible for the system.  When happens when a question of "how do I X with Y" used to be answered with "no, you can't do that" becomes "you do that by doing Z" because the technology changes?  Someone has to go back and provide new answers to all of those duplicates.

Comment: @Cimmanon When the technology change, it should be a new question. If you want to do X with Y 1.0 and X with Y 2.0, it could be 2 completely different answers and you need both because some people might be using Y 1.0 while others are using Y 2.0.

Comment: @Yakk No, duplicate is about questions, not answers. Hence it's "duplicate questions" not "questions that have duplicate answers".

Comment: @Gudradain If two questions are 95% similar they can be linked together without marking them as duplicates, and I agree that they should be. There is even the "Linked questions" sidebar, you seem to be aware of. Of course it doesn't provide the same "value" as duplicate, because it's not for duplicates but similar questions. You're unnecessarily over-complicating things: questions are "duplicate" if they are duplicates, and they should be linked if they are similar. There is nothing more to it.

Comment: @Gudradain I agree with your opinion

Comment: @BartoszKP [duplicates are about finding answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates), and closing them is because " duplicate of... This question has been asked before and already has an answer." *already having an answer* elsewhere.  Duplicate question flagging is about *answers*.  Under what metric should we measure duplication of a question other than what answers them?  Hamming code distance?

Comment: @Yakk What you link, does not contain what you claim. Having an answer elsewhere is an *accidental* property ("**and** already has an answer"), not *essential* of a duplicate question. I'm not proposing any automatic way of finding duplicates so no metrics are necessary. Questions are duplicates if they are asking about the same thing. Two completely different questions can have the same answer, and this doesn't make them duplicates.

Comment: @BartoszKP The very first sentence contains what I claim to be there: ["The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates).  Closing duplicate questions are, and should be, about finding answers.  Closing duplicate questions is otherwise almost always a useless waste of time.

Comment: @Yakk It still only expresses an *accidental* property of duplicate questions. Yes, of course that the mechanism exists to help people finding answers. But it doesn't mean that a question "how to correctly pass complicated state description between functions" and "how to model a domain object" are duplicates because answer to both of them is "use a class". They are about different problems. *Marking/Closing* as duplicates is about answers in terms of purpose, but *being* duplicates is about questions.

Comment: @BartoszKP "Use a class" is not a good answer to either of those questions: I would downvote that answer in both cases.  So no, they are not duplicates of each other under my standard.  Your counter example seems useless as it fails to distinguish between my standard and yours: can you make a better one that is better?

Comment: @Yakk Of course it wasn't a complete answer, it was an example of an essence of such an answer. Obviously I won't include complete exemplary posts here in the comment :| My point was, that both questions pose a different problem (assuming it's well defined: illustrated with particular code samples etc.), but the answer is essentially the same: a class implementation in question's context. Hope you can imagine that it is easy to construct the questions in such a way, that exactly the same implementation would solve them (it's because classes do solve different problems at once).