# How can we handle the duplicate questions on C# JSON?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, duplicate-answers

#### Context:

The [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) + [json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json) tags have a lot of "duplicate" questions and look-alikes.

There are three types of questions:

a. Duplicate of serialize/deserialize 
b. Duplicate of value as properties name 
c. Others.

The a and b are quite common, and always answered, often upvoted.

For as, changing anything in the JSON will make a valid question (for the answerer). Answers display a combination of Visual Studio's built-in menu *Edit* → *Paste Special* → *Paste JSON as Classes* and Json2Csharp, with sometimes a `foreach` to display the result.

Bs can be quite subtle, but present a JSON that looks like:

```
{"518523721":{"Foos":1,"Bar":"abcd"},"527032438":{"Foos":1,"Bar":"abcd"},...}
```

Where a value or an identifier will be used as a property name. Answers may be like As, generated from Json2CSharp, or use `Dictionary<string,string>` with a deserialize example.

#### Problem:

With a lot of open questions with upvotes on both answers and questions.
It's harder and harder to find the duplicates.
It is not harder to find dupes but the one to rule them all.
The adequate target, as many will be linked, but not close, and all of them boils down to the same keywords.

Existing "canonical" answers exist. They are dissolved on many questions, or use old school (anything that is not the last library everyone talked about will be considered obsolete) deserialisation, or a list of methods and libraries (ServiceStack, ms.web, [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json), XYZ parser, etc.).

#### Question:

How can we handle those duplicates?
While the answer will always flag and vote accordingly. The frequency of those questions could be an indication of a bigger problem: Canonical, but not canonical enough?

#### Disclaimer:

It's not a call for close votes and downvotes. Those tags are not bad and unsalvageable; they just have a tendency to be the exact same two questions every time someone finds a JSON. I would like this question to have a clear focus on building and finding great answers; the flag and closure will be easier without putting more work on people already reviewing and curating.

Comment: More generally, a lot of languages have similar issues.  Anything with RegEx or XML, C#'s LINQ as well.  I'm sure there are others.  The problem is many question askers don't want to take the time to take a general approach from a canonical answer and adapt it to their specific use case.  They'd rather have an individual solution (which really doesn't fit the SO model well)

Comment: Nobody wants to close duplicates. [This has been a problem for years](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339261/215552). Stack Overflow doesn't want to solve the issue. Nor do people who have gained thousands of points of rep by repeatedly answering the same question...

Comment: @HereticMonkey, there are greater "evil". Duplicate is almost ok when compare to really bad question. I my self never hit my daily flag limit. It's a lot of effort. perhaps on many tag classical question may have a real good cannonical like C/C++ has.

Comment: You asked "How can we handle those duplicates?" I'm just commenting that there's nothing to do, since very few people want to put in the work to either create canonical questions or to close duplicates of them.

Comment: My english is bad I mean, people are working on other things and if C++ can do it we can do it!

Comment: @HereticMonkey true. It's a lot of work flagging for dupes, only to see maybe one more person voting for the dupe while three people answer the question within the same minute. It's super disheartening and it happens again and again. On the other hand, I've seen a lot of dupe flags where they aren't appropriate where it seems people just don't want to answer the question. When the question is legitimate. Most of the time, it means the question is (wrongly) closed and thus dead because nobody bothers voting to reopen.

Comment: It is not quite clear to me why this cannot be adequately handled by a canonical duplicate. Find a suitable question, edit to polish, and then post a quality community-wiki answer. Use this as a dupe target. If there truly isn’t a suitable seed question, ask and answer your own. Problem solved. I mean, writing good canonicals is *hard*, but it is the only real solution here. It works exceptionally well for the flood of “debug my NullReferenceException” questions.

Comment: @CodyGray first of all, *finding* the dupe can be a hard task when you don't remember enough about it. For example, I keep having that problem with finding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080785/sorting-in-javascript-shouldnt-returning-a-boolean-be-enough-for-a-comparison). It's to do with sorting, JavaScript, and not returning three different values. But "sort boolean" or "return boolean" give the wrong result. You need to search specifically for "sort**ing** return**ing** boolean" to find it. That's the minimal information you need. Try finding that in a month's time...

Comment: (cont) Now multiply that by however many canonical answers there are for your tag of choice. Now comes the next hurdle - getting enough people to vote for the dupe to even close the question. The question might just not get enough traffic to gather enough votes, which leaves it open, or people post answers instead of voting for a dupe. Because an easy might get them a vote or two, a close vote doesn't. Now combine the two and it's a daunting task.

Comment: A solution for finding them is to keep a list in the tag wiki, @vlaz. Also using Google instead of trying to use the site search. There isn’t much that can be done about people not using their close votes, but that’s an entirely different discussion. Note that it is quite well mitigated in the case of canonical dupes, since gold tag badge holders have the power to unilaterally close as a dupe, and, not coincidentally, they’re also the people in the best position to judge whether it’s appropriate to close a particular question as a dupe of the canonical.

Comment: @CodyGray I *am* using Google. Frankly, using the site's search engine almost never finds me what I need, unless I know a LOT of information like view count, votes and/or other stuff. The search string I told you about is a Google search. But if you don't use that magical **ing** suffix you don't get what you need. Golden dupehammers help but aren't the be all and end all solution, as it still needs a gold badge user to get to the question. The whole system is a problem - there is little incentive to close as dupes and, if anything, the gamification promotes *not* doing it.

Comment: *"they just have a tendency to be the exact same two questions every time someone finds a JSON"* - that's general problem, users (including me) can't find an answer and post their duplicate. It's unavoidable until greater AI will appears capable to find duplicates alone. Ask any user with high enough reputation, everyone can name tags for which they seen hundreds of duplicates. In your case it's json + C# (but I think `NullReferenceException` will beat it). What should we do? Nothing special, vote-close as usual.

Comment: @xdtTransform Incentives for finding duplicates have been [proposed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284807/1115360) since the year 2010 (if not earlier). Personally, I think badges would be the way to go, as points would be too much of an immediate reward and point-hunters might then inaccurately flag some questions in their haste for gain.

Comment: I wonder if that can be taken as a hint that we'd need a limited NuGet package for simple but common operations that cover the cases asked about in a more intuitive manner. I can imagine that when starting off on the subject or lacking experiences for other reasons, it's quite confusing and a template doing the thinking for them (at least partially) is a good way to start. I'm thinking of attributing the properties as a simpler way than Fluid API when configuring EF. This kind of approach.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I'd be happy with people not getting points from an answer if the question is later marked as dupe. That will help as well.